# Paragraph ended before \gather was complete error message

Tags: equations, split

This equation gives me the Paragraph ended before `\gather` was complete error. How can I fix it?

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{split}
\frac{dVout}{dpH} & =\frac{214.4 I_{bias} L}{\lambda_p k' W \big(V_{S}- \frac{V_{Ref} -V_{chem}}{1+\frac{C WL}{A_{sen1}}}-V_{T}\big)^3 }+\\
&\frac{107.2 \big(V_{Ref} -V_{chem}\big)\big(V_{S} -\frac{V_{Ref} -V_{chem}}{1+\frac{C WL}{A_{sen2}}}-V_{T}\big)^2 \big(\frac{1}{1+\frac{C WL}{A_{sen1}}}-\frac{1}{1+\frac{C WL}{A_{sen2}}}\big) } {\lambda_p\big(V_{S} -\frac{V_{Ref} -V_{chem}}{1+\frac{C WL}{A_{sen1}}}-V_{T}\big)^3}
\end{split}
\end{gather}
```

Comment: Don't use `split` within `gather`, this is meaningless. Usually, this sort of message comes from a blank line in an amsmath environment.

Comment: I tested the code and needed one more '/' to break the line... That was the problem I think... Now it works

Comment: For fun, have you tried aligned instead of split? It might work better. Otherwise my guess is an error in your code

Comment: unrelated but do not use `\big` use `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` to get correct spacing, and use `V_{\mathrm{ref}}` and `V_{\mathrm{chem}}` as math italic does not work for words

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- You mustn't use `split` inside `gather`. Use either `align` or `equation` instead of `gather`. Better still, use a single `multline` environment.
- Some of the parentheses need to be larger than `\big`. Use `\Big` or even `\bigg`.
- Use either `\mathit` or `\mathrm` for combinations of letters such as "bias" and "chem".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\frac{d\mathit{Vout}}{d\mathit{pH}} 
=\frac{214.4 I_{\mathit{bias}} L}{\lambda_p k' W \Bigl(V_{S}- \frac{V_{\mathit{Ref}} -V_{\mathit{chem}}}{1+
\frac{\mathit{CWL}\mathstrut}{A_{\mathit{sen}1}}}-V_{T}\Bigr)^{\!3\mathstrut} }\\
+\frac{107.2 \bigl(V_{\mathit{Ref}} -V_{\mathit{chem}}\bigr)\Bigl(V_{S} -\frac{V_{\mathit{Ref}} 
-V_{\mathit{chem}}}{1+\frac{\mathit{CWL}\mathstrut}{A_{\mathit{sen}2}}}-V_{T}\Bigr)^{\!2} 
\Bigl(\frac{1}{1+\frac{\mathit{CWL}\mathstrut}{A_{\mathit{sen}1}}}
-\frac{1}{1+\frac{\mathit{CWL}\mathstrut}{A_{\mathit{sen}2}}}\Bigr) } 
{\lambda_p\Bigl(V_{S} -\frac{V_{\mathit{Ref}} -V_{\mathit{chem}}}
{1+\frac{\mathit{CWL}\mathstrut}{A_{\mathit{sen}1}}}-V_{T}\Bigr)^{\!3\mathstrut}}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```